# Django Blogpost absolute_url not working as intended

Tags: python, django, blogs

so I've got the following app which is supposed to be resemble a multi-userblog by simply providing only views for each author.

Everything is working except for the absolute url of the post. (I want to keep it very simple - no need to use publish/draft etc.)

Here is my code:

models.py: http://pastebin.com/pT91DUdZ

```
@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('blog_detail', None, {
        'year': self.created.year,
        'month': self.created.strftime('%b').lower(),
        'day': self.created.day,
        'slug': self.slug
    })
```

views.py: http://pastebin.com/FTb0s97u

```
def post_list(request, page=0, paginate_by=20, username=None, **kwargs):
    author = None
    if username is not None:
        author = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset=author.post_set.created(),
        extra_context = {'author' : author},
        paginate_by=paginate_by,
        page=page,
        **kwargs
    )
```

urls.py: http://pastebin.com/Nv2SRbhe

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url


urlpatterns = patterns('userblog.views',
     url(r'^(?P<username>.*)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
         view='post_detail',
         name='blog_detail'
     ),
     url(r'^(?P<username>.*)/(?P<page>\d+)/$',
         view='post_list',
         name='blog_index_paginated'
     ),
     url(r'^(?P<username>.*)/$',
         view='post_list',
         name='blog_index'
),
```

Thanks for taking a look :)

EDIT: 
I did the following for now. I know it's rather ugly, but I couldn't figure out how to do it properly!

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/blogs/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/' % (self.author.username, self.created.year, self.created.strftime('%b').lower(), self.created.day, self.slug)
```

Comment: You haven't actually stated what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry. The absolute_urls don't seem to work properly. The templatetag object.get_absolute_url returns nothing and when I use the 'view on site' in any blogpost via the adminpanel I get the following error: Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'year': 2013, 'slug': u'blog-post-title', 'day': 30, 'month': 'mar'}' not found.

Comment: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1518/

Answer (score 0):

Your `blog_detail` urlpattern is expecting a username buy you're not passing one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you maybe give me a little hint on how to fix this? Also, when I click on a post_url I get the following Runtime Warning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-03-31 12:44:48.306340) while time zone support is active.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. It should be obvious that the blog_detail pattern as defined in urls.py has a space for username, but you have not put that into your get_absolute_url. Either remove it from the urlpattern, or add it to get_absolute_url.

Comment: I tried that and added 'username' : self.author to get_absolute_url. But it still didn't work, that's why I thought there is more to do than that!